# not refreshing window in sql server 2012

Tags: database, sql-server-2012

I've a problem with SQL Server 2012. I'm running SQL server studio management 2012 and then, after connection to local database I'm trying to add a new query. After click button new query I'm getting wrong window. It's window without upper control panel. What's more main window it's not refreshing. I dunno why. It's refreshing after maximizng window, but not dynamically. I have no idea what's wrong. I've windows 7 64 bit and my version of SQL Studio management is:

```
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio      11.0.3128.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer                 9.10.9200.16521 
Microsoft .NET Framework                    4.0.30319.296 
Operating System                            6.1.7601
```

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed LOTS of graphical / UI bugs with the 2012 SSMS.  Same version (11.0.3128.0).
Guessing you got this resolved by now, but perhaps you just dragged the query window out of the main SSMS window?  I never really use this ability since it treats the "popup" windows as modal and always-on-top, which is annoying.

Frequently, when I resize windows, I get vertical black bars.  When I stretch the window, it normally clears it up, but sometimes I have to min/maximize it to get it back to normal.  Probably a different bug, but [Here's a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evuvv.gif)